# Clojure quadratic formula

Tags: clojure, formula, quadratic

```
(ns quadratic_roots) ;name the program 


(defn quadraticRoots[a b c]
    (/ (+ (- 0 b) (Math/sqrt (- (Math/expt b 2) (* 4 a c)))) (* 2 a)) (/ (- (- 0 b) (Math/sqrt (- (Math/expt b 2) (* 4 a c)))) (* 2 a)))
)
```

This is only the first part of the quadratic formula program I'm writing. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to make the exponent method work. Also, 
I'm having some trouble trying to create the main driver program to implement the function quadraticRoots

Answer (score 2):

You need either `(Math/pow b 2)` or just `(* b b)` to get b^2:

```
(defn quadraticRoots [a b c]
  ; for simple squares, often simplify (Math/pow b 2) => (* b b)
  (let [discriminant (Math/sqrt (- (Math/pow b 2)
                                 (* 4 a c)))
        root-1       (/ (+ (- b) discriminant)
                       (* 2 a))
        root-2       (/ (- (- b) discriminant)
                       (* 2 a))]
    [root-1 root-2]))
```

with result (see [example problem](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratic-functions-equations/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratic-formula-a1/a/quadratic-formula-explained-article)):

```
  ; Example:  x^2 + 4x - 21 = 0
  (let [a 1
        b 4
        c -21]
```

and then

```
(quadraticRoots a b c) => [3.0 -7.0]
```

You may also wish to use `git clone` on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) so you have a working setup to get you going.

---

**Update**

Math formulas (even simple ones) often aren't as recognizable in computer code.  An alternate formulation of the above might look like:

```
(defn quadratic-roots 
  "Solve for the 2 roots of a quadratic equation of the form:

       ax^2 + bx + c = 0 
  "
  [a b c]
  (let [discriminant (Math/sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))
        neg-b        (- b)
        inv-a2       (/ 1 (* 2 a))
        root-1       (* inv-a2 (+ neg-b discriminant))
        root-2       (* inv-a2 (- neg-b discriminant))]
    [root-1 root-2]))
```

Comment: For legibility, I would suggest also extracting a function for the second half of the function: `(let [determinant ..., solve (fn [d] (/ (- d b) 2 a))] (map solve [b (- b)]))`

Comment: Nit-picking: the expression under the square root is normally called the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant). A [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try macro like [infix](https://github.com/rm-hull/infix)

```clj
(use 'infix.macros)

(let [a 1
      b 4
      c -21]
  (infix (- b + √(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)))
;; => 3.0
```

the macro converts your infix expression into below s-exp:

```
(/ (+ (- b) (Math/sqrt (- (Math/pow b 2) (* (* 4 a) c)))) (* 2 a))
```

and evaluate it in this order:

```clj
| | -=> -4
| | | b=> 4
| | | a=> 1
| | | *=> 4
| | | c=> -21
| | | *=> -84
| | | -=> 100.0
| | +=> 6.0
| | a=> 1
| | *=> 2
(infix (- b + √ ...) / (2 * a))=> 3.0
```